# How to display 2 alert boxes in a same method in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can we display 2 (javascript) alerts in aspx ?

if possible can anyone help how to show 2 alerts

```
public void ShowAlert()
        {
            string value = "9494949494";
            string message = "alert on " + value;
            string script = "alert('" + message + "');";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "UserSecurity", script, true);
        }
```

Comment: Where is the code? Tried putting two alert statements one after another? Did it work? What did it show? Any error?

Comment: Above code i am using to get alert but ineed to display one after one...

Comment: In the script you can put two alert statements one after another... Did you try that?

Comment: i put one after another but it shows one alert only.                                                             can you help me Chetan

Comment: Strange ... `script = "alert('" + message + "'); alert('" + message + "')";` this didn't work? Any JavaScript error you see?

Comment: when you call the 1st... call the second from that function

Comment: `function UserSecurity(){  secondUserSecurity() alert( message)}; function secondUserSecurity(){ alert(secondmessage);}`

Comment: Thank you chetan it wokred..

Comment: string script = "alert('" + message + "');" + "alert('" + message1 + "');";

Comment: you can have multiple javascript alert but they will popup one after another. Once you click ok another alert will display and so on. Native javascript can not show multiple alert box but you can use jquery plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public void ShowAlert()
  {
        string value = "9494949494";
        string message = "alert on " + value;
        string script = "alert('" + message + "');";
        string script2 = "alert('" + message + "');";
        var myScripts = new List<String>();
        myScripts.AddRange(script, script2);

        foreach(var s in myScripts)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), 
            "UserSecurity", s, true);
        }

  }
```

UPDATED:

OR a more reasonable approach

```
  public void ShowAlert()
  {
        string value = "9494949494";
        string message = "alert on " + value;
        string script = "alert('" + message + "');";
        string script2 = "alert('" + message + "');";
        var myScripts = script + script2

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page),
        "UserSecurity", myScripts, true);


  }
```

Comment: Why list and loop when you can simply append alerts in single string!

Comment: Thanks a lot Chef_Code.